# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type (modelclass)

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app, it was working fine until now. I have set an adapter in  welcometojungleactivity.class, My adapter class is plantlistadapter, it was working fine even i had completed my work in this class and working on some other class, I don't know how the problem occurred unexpectedly.

welcometojungleactivity.java(Containing RecyclerView)

```
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<plantsWord, plantslistAdapter> mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<plantsWord, plantslistAdapter>(
            plantsWord.class, R.layout.item_plantslist, plantslistAdapter.class, mPlantsDatabaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(plantslistAdapter viewHolder, plantsWord model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getplantImageURL(), model.getplantLocation(), model.getplantName(), model.getplantType());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public plantslistAdapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            plantslistAdapter mplantslistAdapter = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
            mplantslistAdapter.setOnClickListener(new plantslistAdapter.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemlongclick(View view, int position) {
                }
            });

            return mplantslistAdapter;
        }
    };
    mplantsreRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

//plantlistAdapter.java

```
public class plantslistAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private View mView;
    public plantslistAdapter(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

public void setDetails(Context context, String plantImage,  String plantLocation, String plantName, String plantType){
    ImageView imgpreview = mView.findViewById(R.id.plantlist_imgpreview);
    TextView location = mView.findViewById(R.id.plantlist_location);
    TextView plantname = mView.findViewById(R.id.plantlist_plantname);
    TextView planttype = mView.findViewById(R.id.plantlist_planttype);
    Glide.with(context).load(plantImage).into(imgpreview);

    location.setText(plantLocation);
    plantname.setText(plantName);
    planttype.setText(plantType);
        }
       }
```

This is my error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type phyla.admin.com.phyla.plantsWord
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:147)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:136)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:176)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517).......
```

If anyone know how to resolve this please let me know, i think this code is correct because I have checked it and have not changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to know more about what is happening here, but it looks like you're attempting to use a Long type somewhere that there is code to convert a Numeric (likely Integer) type to a custom "word" type. The use of "Word" is interesting here. I've often seen that in programming languages a "Word" is a 16bit unsigned integer used to store bit-patterns, rather than the actual numerical value. It is possible that a Long type simply has too much precision to store in this value. If you're certain the value here should always be < 2^31, than I would suggest converting it to an int before use. Some systems default to using Longs for integral values, so it's possible that this "Worked on your machine" but doesn't work in other situations.

Again, I don't know the system you're working with, so this is pure speculation.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem , actually i mistakenly put an Integer value along the nodes of other values like (plantId, plantImgUrl etc...) When Firebase is trying to retrieving data against my plantWord class, it compare multiple values with a single integer..Btw thanks for your help!!!